# Git checkout to specific directory

Tags: git

So, currently I am working on merging two branches, `A` and `B`.

I'm merging into branch `B`, but I had restructured the project into different directories and would like to do a `git checkout A --path/fileToGet` of sorts (to overwrite is the intention) but into a **different directory in my branch**. To keep revision history for the file, what would be the best thing, do I just checkout the file like normal, `rm` my current file and then `git mv` (or maybe just a regular `mv` and maybe git will follow` it? Or is there a better method to follow?

I had found in some comments here at SO that when using `git diff A:path/file B:anotherPath/file` I am able to compare the two files, so I'm thinking there might be another way, using the `:` to specify from where, to where.

Comment: I did the rm and git move since it's a minor project at the moment, but I'd like a professional answer fro future reference.

Answer (score 0):

`rm` the current directory and then used `git checkout A --path/to/old/location` to check the old file location out.

Comment: I don't want the old file location, I want the new one location, but conserve revision history for the file