# How do I git checkout a specific directory and strip the path to that directory?

Tags: git

I have a mono repo and want to checkout all the files from a path into a directory on my web server.

I know that I can checkout a directory by doing: `git checkout origin/master -- path/to/directory`, but that gives me my files in `path/to/directory`.

I want the checkout files, from the remote directory, in my current directory. So I have tried `git --work-tree=. checkout origin/master -- path/to/directory`. But that does not alter the output directory path.

Right now, I just move the files but this quickly gets tedious (`mv path/to/directory/* .`). Is there a git command that can help me?

This question is similar to this unanswered question: [Git checkout to specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044480/git-checkout-to-specific-directory)

Comment: `git checkout` itself doesn't allow you to do what you describe. However, why do you find that moving the files get tedious? Why not simply run `git checkout ... && mv ...`?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do a deployment to your web server? If so, I would look to tools specific to that task (or at least create some shell scripts).

Comment: While both your suggestions will work, I'm asking the more git knowledge people here, if there is a git way. Perhaps using `--git-dir=`. I know how to work around the problem but that does not make me a better git user or answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use git sparse checkout for this:

```
git clone --no-checkout https://repo.mycompany.com/git/admin_repo
cd admin_repo
git sparse-checkout init --cone
git sparse-checkout set path/to/directory
git checkout
```

See https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout for more information.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I haven’t tried your answer yet but the option `—cone` strikes me as a bit odd. Is it a typo?

Comment: Just checked your link and yes, it’s `—cone`

Comment: This answer works _almost_ perfectly! It also checks out all of the files at the root level and not only _path/to/directory_ but that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a script `checkout_git_dir_and_move_file_here.sh`:

```
git checkout origin/master -- $1
mv $1/* .
rmdir -p $1
```

and place it in `~/bin`. Then you can call it from wherever.

Git is a command-line tool, so it's natural to write shell scripts for dealing with things like this. A lot of more complex git tasks require explicit scripting.

Comment: this is very inefficient if you want to checkout a 1MB folder from a 100GB repo because your first command would first checkout 100GB

Answer (score 1):

While Git can be used as a deployment tool, there are better alternatives. But, we use Git for a very similar task that should work for you. However, this assumes your purpose is to only “checkout” files and not to commit changes back to the repository.

In our case, we have a repository containing a collection of Bash, Perl, and other scripts for different types of test servers. Due to similarities and for sanity’s sake we keep them in one repository under separate directories for each server rather than a repository for each server.

To deploy scripts on a given server, say `ServerA`, we initially create a mirrored clone of the repository locally.

```
cd /opt/repos
git clone --mirror https://repo.mycompany.com/git/admin_repo
```

Updating the mirror as changes are committed to the main repository is performed as follows:

```
cd /opt/repos/admin_repo.git
git fetch --all
```

For this and other servers, scripts are in `/usr/local/cscripts`. To extract scripts for ServerA, which are contained within the repository under `server_a/cscripts`, the following commands are used

```
cd /usr/local/cscripts
rm -rf *
git archive --remote=/opt/repos/admin_repo.git HEAD:server_a/cscripts | tar -x
```

In essence, the resulting tarball is immediately extracted into the current directory without regard for the repository’s path. It’s not a perfect solution, because changes in filenames or subdirectory layouts are not automatically applied, hence the `rm --rf` to ensure a blank slate.

**Edit:**
I failed to mention that we use a mirror of the repository because our current repository server only uses simple HTTPS and does not support `git:` or smart-HTTPS. If your repository is already local or maintained on a better
repository server, you can extract archives directly without a mirror.